# Cannot run private testnet with more than 2 nodes

Tags: testnet

I've been following [this tutorial](https://moneroexamples.github.io/private-testnet/) to set up a private testnet. However it only works with 2 nodes. As soon as I start the 3rd one (with port 48080), I get these errors

```
2018-01-07 03:57:00.286 [P2P0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:743    [127.0.0.1:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2018-01-07 03:57:00.286 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:792    [127.0.0.1:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2018-01-07 03:57:05.287 [P2P4]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:743    [127.0.0.1:38080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2018-01-07 03:57:05.287 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:792    [127.0.0.1:38080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2018-01-07 03:57:34.288 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:743    [127.0.0.1:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2018-01-07 03:57:34.288 [P2P6]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:792    [127.0.0.1:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
```

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Those aren't related to being in testnet, or having 3 nodes, or both at once.

Comment: Some firewall dance going on there maybe ?

Comment: Run with --log-level 1 to get more info on what it's trying to do.

Comment: I think I found the reason. I was discouraged by the error messages at first so I didn't try to mine but actually the network is still synchronized.  I set the log level to 2 and saw "INFO  net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1658 [127.0.0.1:53950 INC] CONNECTION FROM 127.0.0.1 REFUSED, too many connections from the same address", which is obvious since I'm running all the nodes on the same machine. Then I changed max_connections in net_node.inl from 1 to 2, just for testing and the messages did disappear.